# i'm trying to connect to the Coinbase advanced api but i'm getting Coinbase 401 unauth error

Tags: python, digital-signature, python-datetime, coinbase-api

im making a neural network that will allow me to connect to the coinbase api and trade but ive been having authentication errors so far. how do i fix it here is the code?

```
    import configparser
    import http.client
    import json
    import hashlib
    import hmac
    import time
    from datetime import datetime, timezone
    from typing import Tuple, List, Dict, Any
    
    import requests
    
    
    class API:
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(r"D:\repos\user\Coinbase_neural_network\config.ini")
        api_key = config.get('coinbase', 'API_KEY')
        secret_key = config.get('coinbase', 'SECRET_KEY')
    
        @staticmethod
        def generate_signature(timestamp: str, method: str, request_path: str, body: str,
                               secret_key: str = secret_key) -> str:
            signature_string = timestamp + method.upper() + request_path + body
            hmac_object = hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), signature_string.encode(), hashlib.sha256)
            return hmac_object.hexdigest()
    
        @staticmethod
        def get_best_bid_ask(api_key: str = api_key, secret_key: str = secret_key) -> str:
            payload: str = ''
            timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()
            headers: Dict[str, str] = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'CB-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
                'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': API.generate_signature(secret_key, timestamp, "GET", "/api/v3/brokerage/best_bid_ask",
                                                         payload),
                'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            }
            with http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com") as conn:
                conn.request("GET", "/api/v3/brokerage/best_bid_ask", payload, headers)
            res: http.client.HTTPResponse = conn.getresponse()
            data: bytes = res.read()
            conn.close()
            return data.decode("utf-8")
    
        @staticmethod
        def get_brokerage_accounts(limit: int, cursor: str, api_key: str = api_key, secret_key: str = secret_key) -> str:
            payload: str = ''
            timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()
            headers: Dict[str, str] = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'CB-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
                'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': API.generate_signature(secret_key, timestamp, "GET",
                                                         f"/api/v3/brokerage/accounts?limit={limit}&cursor={cursor}",
                                                         payload),
                'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            }
            with http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com") as conn:
                conn.request("GET", f"/api/v3/brokerage/accounts?limit={limit}&cursor={cursor}", payload, headers)
            res: http.client.HTTPResponse = conn.getresponse()
            data: bytes = res.read()
            conn.close()
            return data.decode("utf-8")
    
    
        @staticmethod
        def get_product_candles(product_id: str, start: str, end: str, granularity: str, api_key: str = api_key,
                                secret_key: str = secret_key) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
            timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
            url = f"https://api.coinbase.com/api/v3/brokerage/products/{product_id}/candles"
            params = {
                "start": start,
                "end": end,
                "granularity": granularity
            }
            headers = {
                "CB-ACCESS-KEY": api_key,
                "CB-ACCESS-SIGN": API.generate_signature(secret_key, timestamp, "GET", url, ""),
                "CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP": timestamp
            }
            response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
            response.raise_for_status()
            candles: List[List[float]] = response.json()
            candles_data: List[Dict[str, str]] = [dict(zip(["start", "low", "high", "open",
                                                            "close", "volume"], c)) for c in candles]
            print(candles_data)
            return candles_data
    
        @staticmethod
        def get_market_trades(product_id: str, limit: int, api_key: str = api_key,
                              secret_key: str = secret_key) -> Tuple[List[Dict[str, str]], str, str]:
            payload: str = ''
            timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()
            headers: Dict[str, str] = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'CB-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
                'CB-ACCESS-SIGN':
                    API.generate_signature(secret_key, timestamp, "GET",
                                           f"/api/v3/brokerage/products/{product_id}/ticker?limit={limit}", payload),
                'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            }
            conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com")
            conn.request("GET", f"/api/v3/brokerage/products/{product_id}/ticker?limit={limit}", payload, headers)
            res: http.client.HTTPResponse = conn.getresponse()
            data: bytes = res.read()
            trades: Dict[str, Any] = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
            trade_data: List[Dict[str, str]] = [dict(zip(["trade_id", "product_id", "price", "size", "time", "side", "bid",
                                                          "ask"], t)) for t in trades["trades"]]
            best_bid: str = trades["best_bid"]
            best_ask: str = trades["best_ask"]
            conn.close()
            return trade_data, best_bid, best_ask
    
        @staticmethod
        def create_buy_market_order(client_order_id: str, product_id: str, side: str, order_configuration: str,
                                    api_key: str = api_key, secret_key: str = secret_key) -> str:
            payload: str = json.dumps({
                "client_order_id": client_order_id,
                "product_id": product_id,
                "side": side,
                "order_configuration": order_configuration
            })
            timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()
            headers: Dict[str, str] = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'CB-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
                'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': API.generate_signature(secret_key, timestamp, "POST", "/api/v3/brokerage/orders",
                                                         payload),
                'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            }
            with http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com") as conn:
                conn.request("POST", "/api/v3/brokerage/orders", payload, headers)
            res: http.client.HTTPResponse = conn.getresponse()
            data: bytes = res.read()
            conn.close()
            return data.decode("utf-8")
    
        @staticmethod
        def create_sell_market_order(client_order_id: str, product_id: str, side: str, order_configuration: str,
                                     api_key: str = api_key, secret_key: str = secret_key) -> str:
            payload: str = json.dumps({
                "client_order_id": client_order_id,
                "product_id": product_id,
                "side": side,
                "order_configuration": order_configuration
            })
            timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()
            headers: Dict[str, str] = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'CB-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
                'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': API.generate_signature(secret_key, timestamp, "POST",       "/api/v3/brokerage/orders",payload),
                'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            }
            with http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com") as conn:
                conn.request("POST", "/api/v3/brokerage/orders", payload, headers)
            res: http.client.HTTPResponse = conn.getresponse()
            data: bytes = res.read()
            conn.close()
            return data.decode("utf-8")
```

ive tried iso strtime uninx etc and it all comes out wrong. am i acesing it wrong. im trying to get this done a decent amount of time before black friday so i can buy a new laptop for school and pay off some of my loans and need help.